# Fill or colour in continuous scale through gradient of more than 2 defined colours

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to make a colour gradient through more than low and high defined parameters?

Lets say, on this data:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:100, 
                 b = rnorm(100, mean = 1000, sd = 500))
ggplot(df) +
   geom_point(aes(a, b)) +
   scale_fill_continous(low = "white", high = "black")
         ## as "low" and "high" is all scale_fill_continous() funcion offer
```

Setting the low and high parameters only results in a linear colour gradient, but I want more combined colour gradient, lets say from white to blue and then to black.

Thank you for your attention and answers.

Comment: `scale_fill_gradientn` is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(a=1:100, b=rnorm(100, mean = 1000, sd = 500))
ggplot(df,aes(x=a, y=b, col=b)) + geom_point() +  
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = c("green", "blue","blue", "red","red", "yellow"),breaks = c(0,1000,2000,3000), limits=c(0,3000))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=seq(along=x), y=rnorm(100, mean = 1000, sd = 500)), aes(x=x, y=y, colour=y)) + 
geom_point() + 
scale_colour_gradientn(values=c(0, 1000, 2000, 3000),
colours=c("green", "blue", "red", "yellow"),
rescaler=function(x, ...) x, oob=identity)
```

giving this plot

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

The `colorpanel` function in `gplots` is ideal for this. It produces a spectrum of n colours (e.g., 50) between 2 or 3 colours (middle colour is optional):

```
library("gplots")
scale_fill_continuous <- colorpanel(50, "blue", "red") #2 colours
scale_fill_continuous <- colorpanel(50, "blue", "white", "red") #3 colours
```

There are also various preset functions, e.g., `rainbow(50)`, `greenred(50)` (mid=black), or `bluered(50)` (mid=white).

For the example given:

```
#Generate a colour spectrum
library("gplots")
scale_fill_continuous <- colorpanel(300, "green", "purple", "yellow") 
#Generate data
set.seed(5)
data <- rnorm(100, mean = 1000, sd = 500)
mapping <- ceiling(data/100) #round to index in colour scale
coloured_data <- scale_fill_continuous[mapping] #map to colour sale
```